# How does this integral result come out for the expand $F(x)$ with particle in a box energy eigenfuctions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

F(x)=x(l-x)[image]
and what integral equations were used in this calculation ?

Comment: Looks like you have two integrals: $\int x\sin(ax)=?$ and $\int x^2\sin(ax)=?$, no?

Comment: YES, I use what you are mentioned to do the calculation, however, my answer is not the given result.

Comment: Let me guess: you've got a cosine term there.

Comment: yep，  the sin term are all 0 at n pi , only cos term left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two integrals you have are
$$
\int x\sin(ax),\quad\int x^2\sin(ax)
$$
with solutions
$$
\frac{1}{a^2}\left(\sin(ax)-ax\cos(ax)\right),\quad\frac{1}{a^3}\left(2ax\sin(ax)+(2-a^2x^2)\cos(ax)\right)
$$
The issue remaining is the $\cos(n\pi)$ terms, as expressed by OP's comments. For integer $n$, the values of $\cos(n\pi)$ can be easily pulled from a graph:

[image]
([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions))

Since the pattern of sine and cosine continue as it does from $(0,2\pi)$, one can see that
$$
\cos(n\pi)=\begin{cases}+1 &\text{if $n$ even} \\ -1&\text{if $n$ odd}\end{cases},
$$
which can be written more compactly as,
$$
\cos(n\pi)\equiv\left(-1\right)^n
$$
This is a [fairly standard equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/911716/), which is probably why the author uses it without explanation.